# why does DrawerLayout are not working on sony ericson xperia API 8 - 2.3?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout

I'm develop some application with a slider menu with DrawerLayout and ActionBarDrawerToggle.
everything is going fine but when I'm trying to run this app in "xperia arc" device, the app crashes and not loaded!
i have many devices to check the app on them: 
galaxy s4,
galaxy 2 ,
galaxy note 3,
Lg ,
sony ericsson xperia.

only in **xperia** the app doesnt run!
what the reason!?

help me please i spend on this problem days and hours and not a clue what the reason!

```
Logcat error (Xperia arc) :
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.bba.workclock.MainActivity.getActionBar
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.bba.workclock.MainActivity.settingItems(MainActivity.java:1657)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.bba.workclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:124)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please do not downVote my question is very important to me

Comment: Please include the exception stack trace from LogCat in the question.

Comment: I attached the errors

Comment: Which android API is running the xperia device?

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Caution: Be certain you import the ActionBar class (and related APIs) from the appropriate package:

```
If supporting API levels lower than 11:
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
If supporting only API level 11 and higher:
import android.app.ActionBar
```

Comment: so what should i do? i cant import "android.support.v7.app.ActionBar" from my java code. i have only "android.app.ActionBar"

Comment: Add the android support library : http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar was first introduced with Android 3.0! To make it work for older android versions like 2.3.4 you can extend ActionBarActivity from the v7 support libs.

Comment: take a look at this guide: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Comment: ok.. i added the library but what next? what i need to change in my code? i used  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); and now after i added the lib what i need to change?

Comment: Better just let your Activity extend [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have added android.support.v7 library,replace every `getActionBar()` with `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: Its give me a "undefined" .